# "Go to" command option in SharePoint 2010 workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Do we have "go to" command option in workflow in SharePoint 2010?
If not, kindly suggest any substitute method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nope I don't believe so. If you have a set of actions that may repeat,
>   you will basically have to add them each time after your condition.
>   Yes this will cause a bit of 'duplicate code' but the workflows are
>   more for non programmers so they set it up to be ran in order from
>   step 1 to step 2 to step 3, etc.
>
> You could, however write the workflows in C# (If you know it well
>   enough) and do what you are asking

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000832/go-to-or-jump-action-in-sharepoint-workflow-designer)

Comment: That is, if you have SharePoint running on the same machine you're developing on... which, unless you're development machine has Windows Server, you're gonna have to set up a VM or a special machine for SharePoint development.  Get that?  You have to develop on a machine that's running SharePoint, and SharePoint doesn't run on standard Windows environments... even though most developers have machines that run standard Windows environments... so you have to have a dedicated server JUST for SharePoint development unless you want to RDP into your live box and develop there.  SharePoint is trash.